# Comparison test to show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ is divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to understand something from my lecture notes. They are trying to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ is divergent. In the lecture notes that state that, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ is divergent, which is clearly true. Then just say that by the comparison test so is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(n)}{n}$.

When I apply the comparison test I get the following:

let $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$, let $b_n=\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$. Then we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{\ln(n)}{n}}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\ln(n)}=0$$

However I believe we should get a finite positive number for our test to have worked?

Comment: Hint: you used [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test), but should use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test).

Comment: For $n>2$, $\log(n)>1$.  So, $\frac{\log(n)}{n}>\frac1n$ for $n>2$.

Comment: Ahhh, I used the wrong comparison test

Comment: The finite sum -up to $m$- is $\displaystyle > {\ln\left(m!\right) \over m} \sim \ln\left(m\right)  - 1$ as $m \to \infty$.